# Catch PHP breakpoints in VS with code runner as the executor

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I've installed and set up **Visual Studio Code** with **PHP Debugger**.  I would like to be able to enter break-points, and have them halt execution while I'm running my code with the **Code Runner** extension *without* having to run a web-server that XDebug listens to on some specified port.

Is there a particular launch configuration that will let me do this?  I have this so far - no port mentioned - which I was hoping would work for my purposes, but doesn't.

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
 {
     "name": "Launch currently open script"
     "type": "php",
     "request": "launch",
     "program": "${file}",
     "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
  },
]
```

I can enter a break-point and run the launch configuration, which shows the debugger navigation buttons, but when I run the code with code-runner it simply evaluates and outputs the result.